# Xamarin.Android - Listview within a listview

Tags: c#, android, listview, xamarin.android

Hello sorry for the massive code dump but I have can't quite figure out how to solve this.

For this application I'm making a listview filled with medical conditions and lifestyles affecting diet. So there is the condition listview and an ingredients listview under each conditions' title with a corresponding symbol meaning no or moderate.

I have gotten the condition listview to work fine but when i am calling the ingredients adapter an error shows up at the context parameter saying: 
Argument 1: cannot convert from 'FoodTranslate.TranslateAdapter' to 'Android.Content.Context'
I was just wondering if there are changes to the second lot of code that can fix this.
Thank you in advanced.

```
namespace FoodTranslate
{
    class TranslateAdapter : BaseAdapter<OptionItem>
    {
        private List<OptionItem> Options;
        private Context mContext;

    public TranslateAdapter(Context context, List<OptionItem> items)
    {
        Options = items;
        mContext = context;
    }
    public override int Count
    {
        get { return Options.Count; }
    }

    public override long GetItemId(int position)
    {
        return position;
    }
    public override OptionItem this[int position]
    {
        get { return Options[position]; }
    }

    //customising starts here
    public override View GetView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent)
    {
        View row = convertView;

        if (row == null)
        {
            row = LayoutInflater.From(mContext).Inflate(Resource.Layout.ConditionItem, null, false);
        }

        TextView OptionName = row.FindViewById<TextView>(Resource.Id.OptionName);
        ListView ingOut = row.FindViewById<ListView>(Resource.Id.Ingredients);
        OptionName.Text = Options[position].Name;

//where the error occurs
        IngredientAdapter ingAdapter = new IngredientAdapter(this, Options[position].Ingredients); 


        return row;
    }
}
```

}

Ingredients listview:

```
namespace FoodTranslate
{
    class IngredientAdapter : BaseAdapter<Ingredient>
    {
        private List<Ingredient> Ingredients;
        private Context mContext;

    public IngredientAdapter(Context context, List<Ingredient> items)
    {
        Ingredients = items;
        mContext = context;
    }
    public override int Count
    {
        get { return Ingredients.Count; }
    }
    public override long GetItemId(int position)
    {
        return position;
    }
    public override Ingredient this[int position]
    {
        get { return Ingredients[position]; }
    }

    //Customising starts here
    public override View GetView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent)
    {
        View row = convertView;
        if (row == null)
        {
            row = LayoutInflater.From(mContext).Inflate(Resource.Layout.IngredientItem, null, false);
        }

        TextView IngredientName = row.FindViewById<TextView>(Resource.Id.IngredientName);
        ImageView imgLevel = row.FindViewById<ImageView>(Resource.Id.imgLevel);

        IngredientName.Text = Ingredients[position].name;

        switch (Ingredients[position].level)
        {
            case ("no"):
                imgLevel.SetImageResource(Resource.Drawable.noldpi);
                break;
            case ("yes"):
                imgLevel.SetImageResource(Resource.Drawable.yesldpi);
                break;
            case ("moderate"):
                imgLevel.SetImageResource(Resource.Drawable.moderateldpi);
                break;
        };

        return row;

    }
}
```

}

Answer (score 1):

Try passing `mContext` instead of `this` :-

```
IngredientAdapter ingAdapter = new IngredientAdapter(m, Options[position].Ingredients);
```

Comment: Yes, and also remember to set the adapter